# Graph Bipartiteness

Tags: graphs, bipartite-matching

I have 2 questions regarding Bipartiteness with corresponding examples.

1) Can a non-connected graph be bipartite if it has an isolated vertex? Let's take the following graph:
[image]

I would say YES with this partition:
V<sub>1</sub> = {A, D, G}
; V<sub>2</sub> = {B, C, E, F, H}

But what confuses me is that A is isolated.

Is that a contradiction to the bipartitiness of G ?

2) Is there a rule about the uniqueness of the partitions ? Let's take the following graph:
[image]

choice1:
V<sub>1</sub>= {A, C}; V<sub>2</sub> = {B, D}

choice2:
V<sub>1</sub>= {A, D}; V<sub>2</sub> = {B, C}

Does it matter which one i choose?

Comment: The answer of the first question. Yes, it does not have to be connected. For the second, it depends on what you want. What you have done is a correct bipartite graph though. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: @1.question: is every graph with n vertices and with no edges a biartite graph?

Comment: @2.question: i meant, if it matters which one i choose, when detecting the graph bipartitiness?

Comment: An equivalent characterization of bipartite graphs states that a graph is bipartite if and only if it contains no cycles of odd length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

A graph with two sides L and R such that all edges go between L and R is a bipartite graph.

Hence, your first part is correct and so is your second part. It doesn't matter as long as both are [independent sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29).

Comment: @1.question: is a graph with only 1 vertix and with no edges a bipartite graph? V1 = {v} and V2 = {}

Comment: @moller1111:  Yes, every (finite) graph which is 2-colorable is considered bipartite.  You can have lots of isolated vertices, a star whatever you can think of.  It is bipartite if and only if it is 2-colorable if and only if it does not contain any odd cycles.